# Jquery: Show Div (animated) on Click, Only Close When Different Link Clicked + Only One DIV at a Time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-plugins

[Apologies for the initial way I posted this question!]

I am creating a portfolio type website and I need an effect similar to the one seen here when you click on any item in the "Recent Work" section: http://themes.zenthemes.net/cleanr/

Essentially this is the functionality I'm trying to achieve:

1. Click a link on an item (multiple items will have a link to different content)
2. On click, a div will animate and open with new content (in a pre-defined location)
3. The div that opens will have a close button. If the close button is clicked, the DIV will animate and close.
4. Only ONE of these divs with new content can be displayed at a time. So, if a second link is clicked, the first div should close quickly and the second div should open.

I'm pretty close to a solution with the code below, but am running into one major glitch...

If you open DIV 1 and then open DIV 2, it knows to collapse/hide DIV 1, which is perfect (so only one div is shown at a time).

However, if you open DIV 1 and then click the close (red X) button in DIV 1, it begins to close, but as soon as it closes it re-opend again. I just want it to close and stay closed (until a link is clicked again).

I've tried a few things, but can't get it to play nicely.

**You can see this in action here:** http://jsfiddle.net/tdHTN/1/

(Try clicking the first 'go' button, then clicking the red 'x' that appears to see the problem.)

Here is my CSS:

```
#slidingDiv, #slidingDiv_2{
height:200px;
background-color: #99CCFF;
padding:20px;
margin-top:10px;
border-bottom:5px solid #3399FF;
display:none;}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="slidingDiv" class="toggleDiv" style="clear:both;">
    This is my content for block ONE (1). Isn't it so super interesting?
    <a href="#" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/officeicons/PNG/48/Close.png" width="48" height="48" alt="close" /></a>
```

```
<div id="slidingDiv_2" class="toggleDiv" style="clear:both;">
    This is some super exciting content that I will fill in later. This is block TWO (2)
    <a href="#" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv_2"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/officeicons/PNG/48/Close.png" width="48" height="48" alt="close" /></a>
```

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv"><img src="https://www.bcidaho.com/_images/go-button-trans.gif" alt="Play" width="42" height="41" border="0" align="left" /></a>
<a href="#" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv_2"><img src="https://www.bcidaho.com/_images/go-button-trans.gif" alt="Play" width="42" height="41" border="0" align="left" /></a>
```

Here is my JS:

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.showHide = function (options) {

    //default vars for the plugin
    var defaults = {
        speed: 1000,
        easing: '',
        changeText: 0,
        showText: 'Show',
        hideText: 'Hide'

    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    $(this).click(function () { 

         $('.toggleDiv').slideUp(options.speed, options.easing);    
         // this var stores which button you've clicked
         var toggleClick = $(this);
         // this reads the rel attribute of the button to determine which div id to toggle
         var toggleDiv = $(this).attr('rel');
         // here we toggle show/hide the correct div at the right speed and using which easing effect
         $(toggleDiv).slideToggle(options.speed, options.easing, function() {
         // this only fires once the animation is completed
         if(options.changeText==1){
         $(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText) : toggleClick.text(options.showText);
         }
});

      return false;

});

};
})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function(){

$('.show_hide').showHide({           
    speed: 1000,  // speed you want the toggle to happen    
    easing: ''
}); 


});
```

One other thing I'm trying to accomplish (if possible) is to have the DIV animation slide up instead of slide down. I tried changing "slideUp" to "slideDown", but that didn't work.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

[Note: Script source: http://papermashup.com/jquery-show-hide-plugin/]

Comment: [so] is **not** a place for people to do your work for you.

Comment: Hi Lix... I completely agree. Trust me, had I not spent the past 2 hours looking for a way to accomplish this and trying different things (none of which came close), then I wouldn't be asking for help. Certainly I can keep looking and trying on my own, but I'm hoping someone can give me a push in the right direction. My apologies if my post rubbed you the wrong way as that was not my intention.

Comment: Generally, if you have tried something, you should post it.  To do so, you can click the "edit" link at the end of the question.  Copy/paste the code you wrote with an explanation. If you don't know how to make it look good, thats OK just get it in there and someone may help copy-edit it for appearance later.

Comment: @Lix Apologies for the lack of content in my initial post. I have completely edited it and included the latest version of my HTML,CSS,JS. I hope your weekend is going well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to get this to work properly, after a lot of trial-and-error.

I wanted to make sure to include it here so if other people have this same problem, they can jump right to the solution.

Here is the updated JS:

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.showHide = function (options) {

    //default vars for the plugin
    var defaults = {
        speed: 1000,
        easing: '',
        changeText: 0,
        showText: 'Show',
        hideText: 'Hide'

    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    $(this).click(function () { 

         $('.toggleDiv').slideUp(options.speed, options.easing);    
         // this var stores which button you've clicked
         var toggleClick = $(this);
         // this reads the rel attribute of the button to determine which div id to toggle
         var toggleDiv = $(this).attr('rel');
         // here we toggle show/hide the correct div at the right speed and using which easing effect
         $(toggleDiv).is(':visible') ? $('.toggleDiv').slideUp(options.speed, options.easing) : 
$(toggleDiv).slideToggle(options.speed, options.easing, function() {
         // this only fires once the animation is completed
         if(options.changeText==1){
         $(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText) : toggleClick.text(options.showText);
         }
          });

      return false;

    });

};
})(jQuery);
```

Here is what the DIVs (that show and hide) look like:

```
<div id="slidingDiv" class="toggleDiv" style="clear:both;display: none;">
    This is my content for block ONE (1). Isn't it so super interesting?
    <a href="#" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/officeicons/PNG/48/Close.png" width="48" height="48" alt="close" /></a>
```

```
<div id="slidingDiv_2" class="toggleDiv" style="clear:both; display: none;">
    This is some super exciting content that I will fill in later. This is block TWO (2)
    <a href="#" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv_2"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/officeicons/PNG/48/Close.png" width="48" height="48" alt="close" /></a>
```

The links are the same as in my original question.